How to visualize my PocketBase SQLite database with ChartDB?
I want to visualize my PocketBase SQLite database using ChartDB (https://chartdb.io). Is there a way to do this?
I need to connect my PocketBase database to a database client to run ChartDB's "smart query." What would be the easiest way to connect my PocketBase database to achieve this?
I tried looking for a way to connect my PocketBase SQLite database to ChartDB but couldn’t find clear instructions. I expected to visualize the database schema directly in ChartDB using the "smart query" feature, but I’m unsure how to set up the connection between PocketBase and a database client.
